# Is it possible to upload multiple files to Firebase Storage at once?

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-storage

In my image uploader app I currently have it set up to upload a single file to Firebase by using this code:

```
 private void chooseImage() {
    Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.setType("image/*");
    intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
    startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select Picture"), PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST);
    }
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if(requestCode == PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST && resultCode == RESULT_OK
            && data != null && data.getData() != null )
    {
        filePath = data.getData();
        try {
            Bitmap bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(getContentResolver(), filePath);
            imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
        }
        catch (IOException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
 }

private void uploadImage() {

    Date myDate = new Date();
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
    final String myDateString = sdf.format(myDate);
    String Gap ="/";

    if(filePath != null)
    {
        final ProgressDialog progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
        progressDialog.setTitle("Uploading...");
        progressDialog.show();

        StorageReference ref = storageReference.child(myDateString+Gap+ UUID.randomUUID().toString());
        FirebaseDatabase db = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
        DatabaseReference rootRef = db.getReference().child("PreviousJobs");
        String d = ref.toString();

        rootRef
                .child(myDateString)
                .setValue(myDateString);

        ref.putFile(filePath)
                .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
                        progressDialog.dismiss();
                        Toast.makeText(photoUploader.this, "Uploaded", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                })
                .addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                        progressDialog.dismiss();
                        Toast.makeText(photoUploader.this, "Failed "+e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                })
                .addOnProgressListener(new OnProgressListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onProgress(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
                        double progress = (100.0*taskSnapshot.getBytesTransferred()/taskSnapshot
                                .getTotalByteCount());
                        progressDialog.setMessage("Uploaded "+(int)progress+"%");
                    }
                });
    }
}
```

The XML looks like this:

```
 <Button
    android:id="@+id/btnChoose"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="50dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:text="Choose"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btnUpload"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="50dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:text="Upload"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imgView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="171dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="168dp"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/btnChoose" />
```

What would be the best way to convert this to upload multiple files at once? I'm new to the storage side of Firebase and I'm at a total loss. I've been reading on some posts that it's not possible. Is that actually the case or is there a workaround?

### Edit

Using this code I've managed to get multiple files to upload. but for some reason in-app it only shows one item in the recycleview.

recycle_item.xml

```
 android:layout_height="match_parent"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:weightSum="10">


    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/upload_icon"
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_weight="2"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_attach_file_black_24dp"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/upload_filename"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="6"

        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:text="Filename.type"
        android:textSize="16sp" />
</LinearLayout>
```

photoUploader class

```
     initVariables();

}
private void initVariables() {
    mStorage = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference();

    mSelectBtn = findViewById(R.id.select_btn);
    mUploadList = findViewById(R.id.upload_list);

    mUploadList = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.upload_list);

    fileNameList = new ArrayList<>();
    fileDoneList = new ArrayList<>();

    uploadListAdapter = new UploadListAdapter(fileNameList, fileDoneList);

    //RecyclerView

    mUploadList.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
    mUploadList.setHasFixedSize(true);
    mUploadList.setAdapter(uploadListAdapter);

    mSelectBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
    chooseImage();
        }
    });
}

  private void chooseImage() {
    Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.setType("image/*");
    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_ALLOW_MULTIPLE, true);
    intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
    startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent,"Select Picture"), 
RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE);
}
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent 
    data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if(requestCode == RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE && resultCode == RESULT_OK){

        if(data.getClipData() != null){
            int totalItemsSelected = data.getClipData().getItemCount();

            for(int i = 0; i < totalItemsSelected; i++){

                Uri fileUri = data.getClipData().getItemAt(i).getUri();

                String fileName = getFileName(fileUri);

                fileNameList.add(fileName);
                fileDoneList.add("uploading");
                uploadListAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

                Date myDate = new Date();
                SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
                final String myDateString = sdf.format(myDate);
                String Gap ="/";


                StorageReference fileToUpload = mStorage.child(myDateString+Gap+ UUID.randomUUID().toString());

                final int finalI = i;
                fileToUpload.putFile(fileUri).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
                        FirebaseDatabase sb = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
                        DatabaseReference rootRef = sb.getReference().child("PreviousJobs");


                        rootRef
                                .child(myDateString)
                                .setValue(myDateString);
                        fileDoneList.remove(finalI);
                        fileDoneList.add(finalI, "done");

                        uploadListAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

                    }
                });

            }

            //Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Selected Multiple Files", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        } else if (data.getData() != null){

            Toast.makeText(photoUploader.this, "Selected Single File", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }

    }
}


    public String getFileName(Uri uri) {
    String result = null;
    if (uri.getScheme().equals("content")) {
        Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(uri, null, null, null, 
    null);
        try {
            if (cursor != null && cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                result = 
     cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(OpenableColumns.DISPLAY_NAME));
             }
        } finally {
            cursor.close();
        }
    }
    if (result == null) {
        result = uri.getPath();
        int cut = result.lastIndexOf('/');
        if (cut != -1) {
            result = result.substring(cut + 1);
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

Finally the adapter class:

```
public List<String> fileNameList;
    public List<String> fileDoneList;

public UploadListAdapter(List<String> fileNameList, List<String>fileDoneList){

        this.fileDoneList = fileDoneList;
        this.fileNameList = fileNameList;

    }

    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

        View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.recycle_item, parent, false);
        return new ViewHolder(v);

    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {

        String fileName = fileNameList.get(position);
        holder.fileNameView.setText(fileName);

        String fileDone = fileDoneList.get(position);

        if(fileDone.equals("uploading")){

            holder.fileDoneView.setImageResource(R.drawable.progress);

        } else {

            holder.fileDoneView.setImageResource(R.drawable.checked);

        }

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return fileNameList.size();
    }

    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        View mView;

        public TextView fileNameView;
        public ImageView fileDoneView;

        public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            mView = itemView;

            fileNameView = (TextView) mView.findViewById(R.id.upload_filename);
            fileDoneView = (ImageView) mView.findViewById(R.id.upload_loading);


        }

    }

}
```

Comment: This question was changed rather too dramatically in r3, to the degree that the answer given below could not have been given to the question in that state. I debated whether to revert back to r1 or r2 so that the answer given makes sense - I went for r2 in the end, and then added significant case, spelling, and grammar clean-up.

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing [built into the Firebase Android SDK](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/storage/package-summary) for sending batches. However, you could directly [utilize the Google Cloud Storage API to send batch requests](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/json_api/v1/how-tos/batch), although it's a bit involved.

The first thing you need to know if you want to go that route is id for your Firebase storage "bucket". As described [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/admin/start#use_a_default_bucket), you can just take the bucket name without `gs://` and pass that into the GCS resources.

For example, if my bucket is `gs://kato-sandbox.appspot.com` then I use `kato-sandbox.appspot.com`.

To look up your bucket name in Firebase, visit [your storage page in console.firebase.google.com](https://firebase.corp.google.com/project/_/storage/) and look at the URL listed.

[image]